# React/Jest error: services.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

[image]

I have a ServicesContainer that looks for the servicesReducer to render a list of ServiceCards.

### ServicesContainer

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { ServiceCard } from '../../components'

export class ServicesContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            services: props.state.servicesReducer.services
        }
    }

    onFormSubmit(e, user) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.searchUser(user)
    }

    render() {
        const services = this.state.services;

        return (
            <div className='services-container'>
                <ul>
                    { services.map(service =>
                        <ServiceCard
                            key={ service.name }
                            name={ service.name }
                            description={ service.description }
                            admins={ service.admins }
                            group={ service.group } />) }
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        state
    }
}

const ServicesListContainer = ServicesContainer;
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(ServicesListContainer)
```

### ServicesContainer.test

Everything works fine here, but the test does not like the state I'm passing into it:

```
import React from 'react'
import * as enzyme from 'enzyme'
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json'

import { ServicesContainer } from './ServicesContainer'
import ServiceCard from '../../components/Services/serviceCard'
import { initialServicesState } from '../../reducers/Services/servicesReducer'

const state = {
    servicesReducer: {
        services: initialServicesState
    }
}

const servicesContainer = enzyme.shallow(<ServicesContainer state={ state }/>);

describe('<ServicesContainer /> component', () => {

    it('should render', () => {
        const tree = toJson(servicesContainer);
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

});
```

### ^ the initialServicesState from the servicesReducer

```
export const initialServicesState = {
  services: [
    {
      _id: _id,
      name: "GeoStore",
      description: "Manage store delivery zones",
      admins: [ "Chuck Roe", "Steve Wonder" ],
      group: "Black Flag"
    },
    {
      _id: _id2,
      name: "Rights Manager UI",
      description: "Manage all internal applications and services",
      admins: [ "Chuck Roe", "Steve Wonder" ],
      group: "Black Flag"
    }
  ]
}
```

### ServiceCard component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class ServiceCard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render () {
    const name = this.props.name;
    const description = this.props.description;
    const admins = this.props.admins;
    const group = this.props.group;

    return (
      <section className="service-card">
        <h4>{ name }</h4>
        <p>{ description }</p>
        <em>{ group }</em>
        <div className="services-admins">
          <ul>
            <li>
              { admins.map(admin => admin) }
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </section>
    )
  }
}
```

This is what the Redux State looks like in the ServicesContainer:

[image]

Comment: you need to access services: props.state.servicesReducer.services.services

notice the extra services property (because initialServicesState is an object that contains a services property)

Comment: Yeah that was it, I just realized that myself... want to post your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are building the props with the property "services" duplicated.

here are the relevant parts:

On the component you get state.serviceReducer.services from passed props

```
this.state = {
    services: props.state.servicesReducer.services
}
```

the props are passed here, and services gets the value from the import:

```
import { initialServicesState } from '../../reducers/Services/servicesReducer'

const state = {
   servicesReducer: {
       services: initialServicesState
    }
}

const servicesContainer = enzyme.shallow(<ServicesContainer state={ state }/>);
```

And the import comes from this export that is an object with a services property.

```
export const initialServicesState = {
    services: [
        {
           _id: _id,
           name: "GeoStore",
```

so, you have to either change the export to

```
export const initialServicesState = 
    [
        {
            _id: _id,
            name: "GeoStore",
```

or the props building to

```
const state = {
    servicesReducer: {
        services: initialServicesState.services
    }
}
```

as you had already figured in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to attach the `.services` array to `initialServicesState`. That was what was missing.

```
const state = {
    servicesReducer: {
        services: initialServicesState.services
    }
}
```

[image]